# Merge first list with second list based on standard deviation of second list C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, dataset

Given 2 datasets (which are both a sequence of standard deviations away from a number, we are looking for the overlapping sections):

```
var list1 = new decimal[] { 357.06, 366.88, 376.70, 386.52, 406.15 };
var list2 = new decimal[] { 370.51, 375.62, 380.72, 385.82, 390.93 };
```

I would like to perform a merge with items from `List2` being placed closest to items of `List1`, within a certain range, i.e. merge `List2` element within `5.10` (standard deviation) of `List1` element:

```
357.06
366.88 => 370.51
376.70 => 375.52, 380.72
386.52 => 390.93
406.15
```

The idea is to cluster values from `List2` and count them, in this case element with value `376.70` would have the highest significance as it has 2 close neighbors of `375.52` and `380.72` (where as `366.88` and `386.52` have only 1 match, and the remaining none within range).

Which C# math/stats libraries could be used for this (or would there be a better way to combine statistically)?

If this is more of a computer science or stats question apologies in advance will close and reopen on relevant SO site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `list2` is *sorted* (if not, put `Array.Sort(list2);`) you can try *Binary Search*:

**Given:**

```
  var list1 = new decimal[] { 357.06m, 366.88m, 376.70m, 386.52m, 406.15m };
  var list2 = new decimal[] { 370.51m, 375.62m, 380.72m, 385.82m, 390.93m };

  decimal sd = 5.10m;
```

**Code:**

```
  // Array.Sort(list2); // Uncomment, if list2 is not sorted

  List<(decimal value, decimal[] list)> result = new List<(decimal value, decimal[] list)>();

  foreach (decimal value in list1) {
    int leftIndex = Array.BinarySearch<decimal>(list2, value - sd);

    if (leftIndex < 0)
      leftIndex = -leftIndex - 1;
    else // edge case  
      for (; leftIndex >= 1 && list1[leftIndex - 1] == value - sd; --leftIndex) ;
        
    int rightIndex = Array.BinarySearch<decimal>(list2, value + sd);

    if (rightIndex < 0)
      rightIndex = -rightIndex - 1;
    else // edge case
      for (; rightIndex < list1.Length - 1 && list1[rightIndex + 1] == value + sd; ++rightIndex) ;

    result.Add((value, list2.Skip(leftIndex).Take(rightIndex - leftIndex).ToArray()));
  }
```

Let's have a look:

```
  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
    .Select(item => $"{item.value} => [{string.Join(", ", item.list)}]"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
357.06 => []
366.88 => [370.51]
376.70 => [375.62, 380.72]
386.52 => [385.82, 390.93]
406.15 => []
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
    var list1 = new double[] { 357.06, 366.88, 376.70, 386.52, 406.15 };
    var list2 = new double[] { 370.51, 375.62, 380.72, 385.82, 390.93 };

    double dev = 5.1;

    var result = new Dictionary<double, List<double>>();
    foreach (var l in  list2) {
        var diffs = list1.Select(r => new { diff = Math.Abs(r - l), r })
            .Where(d => d.diff <= dev)
            .MinBy(r => r.diff)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (diffs == null) {
            continue;
        }
        List<double> list;
        if (! result.TryGetValue(diffs.r, out list)) {
            list =  new List<double>();
            result.Add(diffs.r, list);
        }
        list.Add(l);
    }
```

It uses `MinBy` from [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ), but it is easy to modify to work without it.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you don't need extra libs or something else. You can use just LINQ for this.

```
internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var deviation = 5.1M;
            var list1 = new decimal[] { 357.06M, 366.88M, 376.70M, 386.52M, 406.15M };
            var list2 = new decimal[] { 370.51M, 375.62M, 380.72M, 385.82M, 390.93M };

            var result = GetDistribution(list1.ToList(), list2.ToList(), deviation);

            result.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.BaseValue} => {string.Join(", ", x.Destribution)}  [{x.Weight}]"));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static List<Distribution> GetDistribution(List<decimal> baseList, List<decimal> distrebutedList, decimal deviation)
        {
            return baseList.Select(x =>
            new Distribution
            {
                BaseValue = x,
                Destribution = distrebutedList.Where(y => x - deviation < y && y < x + deviation).ToList()
            }).ToList();
        }
    }

    internal class Distribution
    {
        public decimal BaseValue { get; set; }
        public List<decimal> Destribution { get; set; }
        public int Weight => Destribution.Count;
    }
```

I hope it was useful for you.